# PHP Split number from database data by customer A or B

Tags: php, sql, database, split, mariadb

PHP Split number from database data by customer A or B

sample database table "tab1"

```
id   FROM    TO
------------------
1    1000    1999
------------------
```

i want to split to another table
split by value if "50"

i want result to table "tab2"

```
id  FROM    TO
------------------
1   1000    1049
2   1050    1099
3   1100    1149
4   1150    1199
5   1200    1249
6   1250    1299
7   1300    1349
8   1350    1399
9   1400    1449
10  1450    1499
11  1500    1549
12  1550    1599
13  1600    1649
14  1650    1699
15  1700    1749
16  1750    1799
17  1800    1849
18  1850    1899
19  1900    1949
20  1950    1999
```

---

how to by php ?? 
no effect please resolve

```css
   no effect please resolve


<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "number";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$row['from'] = 1000;
$row['to'] = 1999;

$start = $row['from'];
$to = $row['to'];
$step = 50;
$values = array();

$query = "INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES (from, to) ";

for($i = $start; $i <= $to; $i += $step) {
    $values[] = '('.$i.', '.($i + ($step - 1)).')';
}

$query .= implode(', ', $values).';';
?>
```

Comment: Do you want transfer some data to another database table? Which SQL serrver you are using?

Comment: Add this at the end of your script: `$conn->query($query);`

Comment: from and to are reserved word,wrap them in backticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MariaDB you can use a for loop from start value until the end value to create a query to insert values to the table you want.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "number";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Error: '.$conn->connect_error;
    exit();
}

$row['from'] = 1000;
$row['to'] = 1999;

$start = $row['from'];
$to = $row['to'];
$step = 50;
$values = array();

$query = "INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES ";

for($i = $start; $i <= $to; $i += $step) {
    $values[] = '(DEFAULT, '.$i.', '.($i + ($step - 1)).')';
}

$query .= implode(', ', $values).';';
if (!$conn->query($query)) {
    echo $conn->error;
}
```